# merge multiple excel workbooks into one

Tags: excel, vba

I have several excel files starting with VW and I want the sheets with all the data to import into a new workbook AEKO. the macro works . user can select the folder where all the workbooks sit. the issue is that in the new created workbook only the sheet from the first excel file got copied and the rest sheets got renamed as well but are blank. why?

here is the VBA code

```
Sub MergeWorkbooks()
    
        Dim myFolder As String
        Dim myFile As String
        Dim myPath As String
        Dim myExtension As String
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim j As Integer
        Dim myWorkbook As Workbook    
        Dim mergeWorkbook As Workbook    
        Dim sheetName As String
    
        'Prompt user to select folder
        With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)    
            .Title = "Select a folder with Excel workbooks"    
            .AllowMultiSelect = False    
            If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub    
            myFolder = .SelectedItems(1)    
        End With      
    
        'Set path and extension    
        myPath = myFolder & "\"    
        myExtension = "*.xlsx"       
    
        'Create new workbook for merging    
        Set mergeWorkbook = Workbooks.Add
    
        'Loop through files in folder    
        myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)
    
        Do While myFile <> ""
    
            'Open only workbooks with name starting with "VW"    
            If Left(myFile, 2) = "VW" Then    
                Set myWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(myPath & myFile)    
                'Rename sheets with Excel file name without extension    
                sheetName = Left(myFile, Len(myFile) - 5)
    
                For i = 1 To myWorkbook.Sheets.Count    
                    myWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name = sheetName    
                Next i
    
                'Copy data to merge workbook    
                myWorkbook.Sheets.Copy After:=mergeWorkbook.Sheets(mergeWorkbook.Sheets.Count)    
                myWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False    
            End If
    
            myFile = Dir    
        Loop    
       
    
        'Delete Sheet1 from merged workbook    
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'suppress alert        
        On Error Resume Next              'continue if Sheet1 is not found    
        mergeWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Delete    
        On Error GoTo 0                   'resume normal error handling    
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True  'turn alert back on       
    
        'Save merged workbook with name "AEKO" in the selected folder    
        mergeWorkbook.SaveAs myPath & "AEKO.xlsx"       
    
        'Close merged workbook    
        mergeWorkbook.Close    
        'Open the new workbook just created    
        Workbooks.Open myPath & "AEKO.xlsx"    
       
End Sub
```

Comment: `myWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name = sheetName` you can't give multiple sheets the same name

Comment: it doesn't give me an error,it gives the sheet a name of the file but only the first heet has a data and the rest of the sheets are blank

Comment: Does each source workbook have only one sheet?

Comment: in my case yes but it would be fine to copy all sheets if multiple in one workbook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
For i = 1 To myWorkbook.Sheets.Count    
                       
                'Copy data to merge workbook    
                myWorkbook.Sheets(i).Copy After:=mergeWorkbook.Sheets(mergeWorkbook.Sheets.Count)    
                mergeWorkbook.Sheets(mergeWorkbook.Sheets.Count).Name = sheetName & i
Next i
myWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
```